# Geforce RTX in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view

Is there any prediction when blender will have in the viewport all the features of the Geforce RTX graphics card?

mainly the GI?

thanks

Comment: Blender likely won't implement feature that is only available to a small subset of the supported hardware. It would also make the appearance inconsistent because the render result would depend on the features the GPU supports. I doubt that the RTX GI could be easily integrated with the way Eevee currently works. That being said, Blender is open source so somebody with the required experience might implement it anyway.

Comment: That's a question for a forum and not that well suited for stackexchange, I think. But I'll give you my guess: Eevee (i.e. the viewport) will not support RTX in the near future (it's using OpenGL and afaik there is currently no way to use RTX in there, but I might be completely off track) but Cycles is right now getting support directly from Nvidia to speed up rendering with RTX, see https://code.blender.org/2019/07/accelerating-cycles-using-nvidia-rtx/